# A uniform convergence counter example?

Tags: analysis

Can anyone think of a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly but $\int_0^\infty f_n \nrightarrow \int_0^\infty f$    ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the constant functions $f_n=\frac{1}{n}$. They converge uniformly to zero, but $\int_0^\infty f_n =\infty$, and $\int_0^\infty f=0$.

Answer (score 1):

One can even find an example using a  sequence of improperly integrable functions, take $f_n={1\over n}\chi_{[0,n]}$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function on the set $A$.